# DB2 Matching on different data types

Tags: python, db2, ibm-midrange, pyodbc

I have to tables that have a `join` field but they aren't matching data types.  One is a String and one is a Decimal. 
When I select them using pyodbc sql query, I can use the following to get them to return identical results:

`int(trim(imus15))`

`int(substr(cmcsno, 1, 6))`

However I get the following error when I run this join:

```
[DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0802 - Data conversion or data mapping error. (-802)
```

I have tried:

`CAST(TRIM(IMUS15 AS INTEGER)) = int(substr(cmcsno, 1, 6))`

I cannot determine how to join on these two fields.

IMUS15 would = `'112303      '`

CMCSNO would = `112303`

Comment: Are you sure you only want to join on the first 6 digits of CMCSNO?

Comment: @jamesallman yes.  That field is only 6 characters in length. I'm going to try your solution when I get a change, I had to manually put this together for the need.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: If you don't specifically need to `SUBSTR` just use the `CHAR` function or implicit conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a non-numeric value in the `IMUS15` field somewhere in the table.

The quickest solution is an explicit character comparison:

```
JOIN TABLE2 ON IMUS15 = CHAR(CMCSNO)
```

For example:

```
WITH TABLE1 AS (SELECT '112303      ' IMUS15 FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1),
TABLE2 AS (SELECT 112303 CMCSNO FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1)
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
JOIN TABLE2 ON IMUS15 = CHAR(CMCSNO)
```

Comment: You probably don't have to trim `IMUS15` as DB2 for IBM i will ignore trailing blanks on the compare. And, `SUBSTR(CMCSNO,1,6)` will generate a fixed length string, potentially with trailing blanks.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy I did a quick test and you are correct.  I also noticed that it implicitly casts `IMUS15` to numeric by default for the comparison.

Comment: @jamesallman this worked.  Not sure how I didn't think of that one, couldn't see the forest for the trees I guess. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I did some testing to reproduce your issue ( i am guessing at the definitions of `IMUS15` and `CMCSNO`):

```
create table jmmlib.table1
  (imus15   char(15),
   data1    char(25));

create table jmmlib.table2
  (cmcsno   dec(6,0),
   data1    char(25));

insert into jmmlib.table1
  values ('123456', 'test key 1'),
         ('1123a', 'non-numeric key'),
         ('555', 'short key');

insert into jmmlib.table2
  values (123456, 'numeric key 1'),
         (1123, 'no valid match'),
         (555, 'short numeric key');

select * 
  from jmmlib.table1
  full outer join jmmlib.table2 on imus15 = char(cmcsno);
```

The result is:

```
IMUS15          DATA1             CMCUSNO   DATA1
--------------  ----------------  --------  -----------------
123456          test key 1        123,456   numeric key 1            
1123a           non-numeric key   <null>    <null>
555             short key         555       short numeric key        
<null>          <null>            1,123     no valid match
```

Note, all you need to do is cast CMCSNO to character, no other gyrations are necessary.

Ways that produce SQL0802 - Data conversion or data mapping error:

```
join on imus15 = cmcsno

join on trim(imus15) = cmcsno

join on dec(imus15,6,0) = cmcsno
```

In all of these the conversion (implicit or explicit) is `imus15 to decimal` where the non-numeric key causes the SQL0802.